# Where were the details of Margulis's 1969 paper published?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, lie-groups, ergodic-theory

I am referring to "G. A. Margulis. Certain applications of ergodic theory to the investigation of manifolds of negative curvature. Functional Anal. Appl. 3 (1969), no. 4, 335–336" which is a two-page announcement of results. (https://doi.org/10.1007%2FBF01076325)

Comment: It might help if you summarize the contents of that two page announcement. The text of the link you gave is behind a paywall.

Comment: Afaik, Margulis never published a detailed version of this paper, but it was generalized by various authors in the last 50+ years (including Margulis himself). The paper itself contains 6 different theorems. I think, you should specify which of these theorems you are actually interested in.

Comment: I see. My only interest is as a mathematical tourist, so in that sense I'm interested in all of the theorems.

Comment: You should have a look at Margulis' book https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540401216. You may also want to have a look at "C. Toll: A multiplicative asymptotic for the prime geodesic theorem, Ph.D. Thesis, University of Maryland, 1984" written under the guidance of Anatole Katok (and unpublished but with the details then given in the Katok-Hasselblatt book).

Comment: Thanks very much!